# Forcing a Pivot to always return 12 rows representing 12 months regardless of data available

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot-table

I want to modify my script to always return 12 rows. Problem is, if only a few records it will only show say Oct and a value. I use the data to feed a graph so if no data i'd like to show Jan 0, Feb 0 and so on, any ideas anyone?

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year(TransactionDateTime))
            FROM Quotations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 
    'SELECT [month], ' + @Cols + '
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3) as [month], 
            datepart(month,TransactionDateTime) as [monthNum], 
            year(TransactionDateTime) as [year],
            isnull(count(*),0) as Total 
        FROM quotations
        group by  left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3), datepart(month,TransactionDateTime), year(TransactionDateTime)
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR [year] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS QuotationResults
    ORDER BY QuotationResults.MonthNum;';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

[image: So if I only have 1 record in table I get one row but I want 12 rows the rest with 0]

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: So I get one row if only 1 record in table but I want 11 more rows showing 0.

Comment: That's not usable, can you atleast post some date from the `Quotations` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create first all month-year combinations then do a `LEFT JOIN` on `Quotations` table to achieve the desired result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year(TransactionDateTime))
            FROM Quotations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 
    'SELECT [month], ' + @Cols + '
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t.[month],
            t.m AS [monthNum], 
            t.y AS [year],
            ISNULL(COUNT(q.TransactionDateTime), 0) AS Total 
        FROM (
            SELECT
                m = m.N,
                y = y.N,
                [month] = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, m.N-1, DATEADD(YEAR, y.N-1900, 0))), 3)
            FROM (VALUES 
                (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
            )m(N)
            CROSS JOIN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    YEAR(TransactionDateTime) AS N
                FROM Quotations
            )y
        )t
        LEFT JOIN Quotations q
            ON YEAR(q.TransactionDateTime) = t.y
            AND MONTH(q.TransactionDateTime) = t.m
        GROUP BY
            t.month, t.m, t.y
    ) AS S
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR [year] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS QuotationResults
    ORDER BY QuotationResults.MonthNum;';


EXECUTE(@query);
```